# Duplicating an array 1:1 in zsh

Tags: zsh

Although it seems fairly simple, there is a small nuance to the obvious solution.

The following code would cover most situations:

```
arr_1=(1 2 3 4)
arr_2=($arr_1)
```

However, empty strings do *not* copy over. The following code:

```
arr_1=('' '' 3 4)
arr_2=($arr_1)
print -l \
  "Array 1 size: $#arr_1" \
  "Array 2 size: $#arr_2"
```

will yield:

```
Array 1 size: 4
Array 2 size: 2
```

How would I go about getting a *true* copy of an array?

Answer (score 3):

It would be an "[Array Subscripts](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts)" issue, so you could properly specify an array subscript form to select all elements of an array ($arr_1 for instance) within double quotes:

```sh
arr_1=('' '' 3 4)
arr_2=("${arr_1[@]}")
#=> arr_2=("" "" "3" "4")
```

Each elements of `$arr_1` would be properly surrounded with double quotes even if it is empty.

> A subscript of the form ‘[*]’ or ‘[@]’ evaluates to all elements of an array; there is no difference between the two except when they appear within double quotes.
> ‘"$foo[*]"’ evaluates to ‘"$foo[1] $foo[2] ..."’, whereas ‘"$foo[@]"’ evaluates to ‘"$foo[1]" "$foo[2]" ...’.
> ...
> When an array parameter is referenced as ‘$name’ (with no subscript) it evaluates to ‘$name[*]’,
>
> -- [Array Subscripts, `zshparam(1)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts)

And empty elements of arrays will be removed according to "[Empty argument removal](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules)", so

```sh
arr_2=($arr_1)
#=> arr_2=(${arr_1[*]})
#=> arr_2=(3 4)
```

Above behavior is not good in this case.

> 24. Empty argument removal
> If the substitution does not appear in double quotes, any resulting zero-length argument, whether from a scalar or an element of an array, is elided from the list of arguments inserted into the command line.
>
> -- [Empty argument removal, Rules Expansion `zshexpn(1)`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules)